# Lightning Component tab page does not load?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Is anyone successful in creating a Lightning Component Tab after Spring 16 release. We were successfully able to create Lightning Component tab before Spring 16. After Spring 16 release, when we click on the 'New' button to create Lightning Component Tab, if keeps on loading forever. Let me know if there is any other way to create Lightning Component tab.

Comment: @ Tara, Just tried ..Same for me...Keep on loading and then time limit exceeded...!!

Comment: Finally, I was able to create the Lightning component tab. It is taking too long to load the page after clicking the New button. I did not receive the limit exceeded message though!!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I was able to create the Lightning component tab. It is taking too long to load the page after clicking the New button. I did not receive the limit exceeded message though!!

Answer (score 0):

Known issue that is being worked on - actually a preexisting performance problem that appears to have gotten worse.